# How to add custom css for Angular PrimeNg component

Tags: css, angular, sass, primeng

Hi i am using PrimeNg component in my Angular project. I tried ':host ::ng-deep', ':host-context(), as per PrimeNg document and Angular document. But nothing works.

PrimeNg docs for custom css:
[enter link description here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/theming)

Angular Document:

[enter link description here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Please suggest me the best way to add custom style for PrimeNg Component.

Answer (score 0):

Share some samples of how you are using it.
In general,

1. Inspect you primeng component and get the exact class for which you need to apply css
2. sample : below is applicable for all tooltip text. If it is required for some specific Angular component, then add style class
   `::ng-deep .ui-tooltip-text {  font-size:12px;     font-family: sans-serif; }`

Comment: #Divya J - I tried this. Please read this - https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep